# How to obtain the unique record of a cross joined table based on the dates of two different columns?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation, ranking

I have quite a complex logic to create. I have some client clinic encounter data which has historical testing results, `R_DATE_TESTED`, `R_RESULT` mapped to each client (`P_CLIENT_ID`) for each `P_DATE_ENCOUNTER`.

| RECORD_ID | P_CLIENT_ID | R_CLIENT_ID | P_DATE_ENCOUNTER | R_DATE_TESTED | R_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 302950 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 302951 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 302952 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 302953 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 302954 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 302955 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 302956 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |
| 302957 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 302958 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 302959 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 302960 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 302961 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 302962 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 302963 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |
| 302964 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 302965 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 302966 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 302967 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 302968 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 302969 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 302970 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |
| 302971 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 302972 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 302973 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 302974 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 302975 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 302976 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 302977 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |
| 302978 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 302979 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 302980 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 302981 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 302982 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 302983 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 302984 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |
| 302985 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 302986 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 302987 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 302988 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 302989 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 302990 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 302991 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |
| 302992 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 302993 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 302994 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 302995 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 302996 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 302997 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 302998 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |
| 302999 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-07-25 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 303000 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-07-25 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 303001 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-07-25 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |
| 303002 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-07-25 | 2019-06-28 | 20.0 |
| 303003 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-07-25 | 2019-08-19 | 42.0 |
| 303004 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-07-25 | 2020-04-20 | 40.0 |
| 303005 | 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-07-25 | 2021-06-03 | 20.0 |

The data is already sorted. How can I obtain the unique record for each Client encounter (group `P_CLIENT_ID AND P_DATE_ENCOUNTER`) where  `R_DATE_TESTED < R_DATE_ENCOUNTER` (but the most recent of that). Moreover if `R_DATE_TESTED < R_DATE_ENCOUNTER` is not true; it returns nulls

The result from logic should be as below:

| P_CLIENT_ID | R_CLIENT_ID | P_DATE_ENCOUNTER | R_DATE_TESTED | R_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2016-12-21 | NaN | NaN |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-02-21 | NaN | NaN |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-04-25 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-06-21 | 2017-03-07 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2017-09-04 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-01-08 | 2017-08-03 | 20.0 |
| 25835 | 25835.0 | 2018-04-03 | 2018-03-23 | 20.0 |

The idea is that for each `P_CLIENT_ID`, each `P_ENCOUNTER_ID` is returned with it's most recent previous `R_RESULT`(latest result prior to the encounter). If a CLIENT has no Results which are before the `P_DATE_ENCOUNTER`, i.e. (`R_DATE_TESTED` is not < `P_DATE_ENCOUNTERED`) then it returns nulls for those columns (As can be seen for the first two records). I thought maybe a combinination of using some ranking over the partition and `.ffill()` but really am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo can use this code:

```py
import numpy as np

# df - your DataFrame

group = df.groupby(['P_CLIENT_ID', 'P_DATE_ENCOUNTER'])

def foo(df):
    result = df.loc[df.P_DATE_ENCOUNTER>df.R_DATE_TESTED, ['R_DATE_TESTED', 'R_RESULT']].tail(1).reset_index()
    if not result.empty:
        return result
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]], columns=['RECORD_ID','R_DATE_TESTED', 'R_RESULT'])


group.apply(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but my dataframe is 2 millions rows big and the operation takes 3,5 hours and memory crashes my notebook eventually. Is there a better way to minimize memory use?

Comment: You can do the same thing only using the dask dataframe. It allows you to parallelize calculations and controls memory usage. Also, consider the library https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel.